# Can i hide the query params from the URL?

Tags: ember.js

In my Ember.js Application, I am dealing with query params for list updates. I have one strange use case, in which I don’t the URL to be updated with certain query params. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you want to reload your model with parameters that are different than the ones in your application route? And you keep your application route parameters synced using queryParams?

In your route's model function you can filter your model data by the same  query params (that appear in the address bar) but you can add some logic that extracts additional parameters either from the controller or other place and these parameters the data fetching query. Example:

```
    model: function(queryParams) {
        var params = queryParams;
        params.additional_filter = this.controllerFor('mycontroller').get('additional_filter');

        return this.store.find('mymodel', params);
    }
```

Also if you want to explicitly reload the model you will need to call Router.refresh() function.